# SOAP REQUEST to vies service

Tags: java, soap

i need to create a SOAP request to check witch "vat" exist in [this archive](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/)
 by using [this web service](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService). This is my code

```
  import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;
   import javax.xml.rpc.Service;
   import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
 import javax.xml.soap.*;

    public class test_vies {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



    String endpoint="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService";
    String action="";
    callSoapWebService(endpoint, action);
}
private static void createSoapEnvelope(SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws SOAPException {
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String myNamespace = "urn";
    String myNamespaceURI = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);



    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("countryCode", myNamespace);
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBody.addChildElement("vatNumber", myNamespace);
    soapBodyElem.addTextNode("IT");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("05006900962");
}

private static void callSoapWebService(String soapEndpointUrl, String soapAction) {
    try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction), soapEndpointUrl);

        // Print the SOAP Response
        System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        soapConnection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String soapAction) throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

    createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage);

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message, just for debugging purposes */
    System.out.println("Request SOAP Message:");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println("\n");

    return soapMessage;
}


}
```

I keep getting a 404 response even if the URL is correct. What may be the problem? `soapAction`? or pheraphs I need to use a different way to use the WS?
I'm pretty new to java, and I cant get my head around this.

Comment: Even i try to open the given URL in browser i get 404

Comment: this is the WSDL im getting the url from:http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

Comment: WSDL is valid. Can u use this WSDL in SOAP UI or some other similar tool?

Comment: no i cant: i have to import this code (so i cant use any external copyrighted code) into my employer's software. So i have to make the whole code

Comment: SOAP UI is open source :)

Comment: That is nice, but i already asked and they said i cant use it. So i have to make it on my own

Comment: Yes, the code you have to make your own. SOAP UI is a tool to test Webservices. I tried to send a message to this web service , but no response.

Comment: i tried with the WSDL and got a response. maybe i have to send the request to the WSDL?

Comment: I am not very sure , normally we use wsdl2java utility shipped with axis2 binary distribution as well to generate stubs.

Comment: Some Reference here: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html
if u are using Eclipse:
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user/tasks/create_client.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in:

```
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("countryCode", myNamespace);
SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBody.addChildElement("vatNumber", myNamespace);
soapBodyElem.addTextNode("IT");
soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("05006900962");
```

It should be:

```
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("checkVat", myNamespace);
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("countryCode", myNamespace);
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("IT");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("vatNumber", myNamespace);
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("05006900962");
```

Comment: What should it be ? It seems that your response is missing an important chunk :)